# java.lang.InstantiationException second time

Tags: java

I have a little problem here and need me some opinions.

Here is a peace of code

```
@XmlRootElement
public abstract class Article {
    // quert params and name of xml elements
    private String name;
    private String author;
    private String description;
    private String picture_url;
    private double price;
    private int id;

    public Article() {
    }

    public Article(String name, String author, String description, String picture_url, double price, int id) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.author = author;
        this.description = description;
        this.picture_url = picture_url;
        this.price = price;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public String getPicture_url() {
        return picture_url;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

And also i have class CD that extend Article. The problem is when i try to create a new Article with POST request in REST application is thrown me exception every time but i provide the no arg constructor also in CD class? What is the catch here ?

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/articles")
public List<Article> gellAllItems(){
    return new ArrayList<>(repo.get().values());
}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/articles/{articleId}")
public Article get(@PathParam("articleId") int id) {
    return repo.get(id);
}

@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/articles")
public Article create(Article article)  {  // return a specific response with entity
    repo.create(article);
    return article;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your class is `abstract`. It cannot be instantiated. Remove the abstract and it should work.